# value assignment to integer datatype in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, types

In a C# application, `int` data type variable has been assigned with value `0x200`. I didn't understand what kind of format it is. Also, if I try to write same statement in vb.net it gives me an error. Pls help

Comment: it's a [hexadecimal integer literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: the VB version is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711649(v=vs.71).aspx). In your case it should be `&H200`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[0x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) means the following value (in this case 200) is in HEX. [200 Hex  is equal to 512 decimal](http://easycalculation.com/hex-converter.php)

**In C#**

```
int i=0x200;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i=512;
```

**In VB.net this can be written as**

```
Dim x=512
```

OR

```
Dim x = &H200
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#

```
int x = 0x200;
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

In VB.NET

```
Dim x = &H200
Console.WriteLine(x)
```

It is just an assignement of a constant expressed with the Hexadecimal notation to a variable

Answer (score 0):

For code conversion I recommend something like [developerFusion Code Converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), it is great for putting a code snippet/example you find on the web in `C#` and having it convert to `VB.NET`. It will also convert from `VB.NET` to `C#`, as well as support for converting `Python` or `Ruby` (the .NET implementations of those being `IronPython` and `IronRuby`).